# Export DataBase with MySQL Workbench with INSERT statements

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to export the DataBase i have at MySQL Workbench but I am having troubles to generate the INSERT statements on the .sql file.

I order to export the data, I do the reverse engineering for the database i want to export. Then, i go to

> File / Export/ Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script

And once in there, i select the option **Generate INSERT Statements for Tables**.

The result only generates the code for the create tables.

Is there any way to create the insert statements for the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**For older versions:**

Open MySQL Workbench > Home > Manage Import / Export (Right bottom) / Select Required DB > Advance Exports Options Tab >Complete Insert [Checked] > Start Export.

---

**For 6.1 and beyond, thanks to ryandlf:**

Click the management tab (beside schemas) and choose Data Export.

Comment: Only to add a note: To do this, needs mysql running as a service.

Comment: You can select just individual tables too. Thought I'd mention since that's what I was looking for.

Comment: In 6.1 click the management tab (beside schemas) and choose Data Export.

Comment: It's the "Management" section but the tab is named "Administration".

Comment: In version 8.0 it is under tab Server / Data Export.

Answer (score 36):

I had some problems to find this option in newer versions, so for Mysql Workbench 6.3, go to schemas and enter in your connection:

[image]

---

### Go to Tools -> Data Export

[image]

---

### Click on Advanced Options

[image]

---

### Scroll down and uncheck `extended-inserts`

[image]

---

Then export the data you want and you will see the result file as this:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If you want to export just single table, or subset of data from some table, you can do it directly from result window:

1. Click export button:
   [image]
2. Change Save as type to "SQL Insert statements"
   [image]

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using mysqldump tool in command-line:

```
mysqldump your_database_name > script.sql
```

This creates a file with database create statements together with insert statements.

More info about options for mysql dump: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

Comment: Thats so quick and super awesome. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL `Workbench 6.1`.

I had to click on the `Apply changes` button in the insertion panel (only once, because twice and MWB crashes...).

You have to do it for **each of your table**.

[image: Apply changes button]

### Then export your schema :

[image: Export schema]

### Check `Generate INSERT statements for table`

[image: Check INSERT]

### It is okay !

[image: Inserts ok]

Answer (score 3):

Go to Menu Server and Click on Data Export. There you can select the table and select the option Dump Structure and Data' from the drop-down.

Answer (score 2):

For the latest version of MySql Workbench

1. Click on the Server menu in the top menu bar
2. Select 'Data Export' submenu
3. It will open up the Object Selection window where you can select the appropriate database which has the desired tables
4. Once you select the database in the left side all the tables will appear in the right side with radio buttons
5. Select the radio buttons in front of needed tables
6. Just below the table selection you can see a dropdown to select Dump Structure Only or Data only or Structure & Data
7. Under Objects to Export tick the box if you need stored procedures or events also. If you don't need those then untick those
8. Under export option change the exporting file name and path
9. If you want to create the schema once you import the dump file then tick include create schema
10. Press Start Export button in the right-hand side corner. once it successful the summary will be showing in the Export progress tab