# how to get code from ER Diagram I designed in mysqlWorkBench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to make a database in MySQL, but when I draw my ER diagram in MySQL Workbench I don't know how to get code from it and copy it into a MySQL script.
How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export tables with MySQL Workbench with INSERT statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255685/export-tables-with-mysql-workbench-with-insert-statements)

Answer (score 1):

Select the File, Export, Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script menu item to start the Forward Engineer SQL Script wizard.

Please refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-forward-engineering-sql-scripts.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File` then `Export` and then `Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script`.

Hope this works for you