# MySQL Table data ARCHIVING

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, archive

I have a management information system in java desktop application with MySQL as my database. I want to archive all my old data. Example I have my Event_Table and the Event recorded in that table is 1 year ago already, I want it to be archived in a way that it will not be searchable in my system and database but I will just save it somewhere in my computer (mysqldump) and restore it if needed. Can you please help me? I am doing the sql statement code inside my java program to handle my MySQL data. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may consider:

1. To store archived records in tables with [ARCHIVE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/archive-storage-engine.html)  storage engine, which is designed specifically for this purpose
2. Use [MySQL event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) or a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to run a sql script of a stored procedure to transfer data from factual to archived tables on a schedule of your preference (daily, weekly, monthly, ...etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL-Workbench, you can export data from there, it is much easier.

*Open MySQL Workbench > Home > Manage Import / Export (Right bottom) / Select Required DB > Advance Exports Options Tab >Complete Insert [Checked] > Start Export.*

[Export tables with MySQL Workbench with INSERT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255685/export-tables-with-mysql-workbench-with-insert-statements)

Comment: Is using ARCHIVE STORAGE ENGINE will not add size in my database? And is it generating its own sqldump? or zip?

Comment: It generates a sql dump (with insert statements for each row), so you can reimport the data easily.

Comment: where can I find that sqldump it generates?

Comment: You can select the destination. Just follow the steps described in the answer and you will know.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. so ARCHIVE STORAGE ENGINE is this process '1. I will create a (example table ) tblArchive 2. I will transfer all my old data a year ago from my tblEvent table to tblArchive (I still don't know what is the process of this) 3. I will no longer search those data in my tblEvent 4. tblArchive will automatically generate an sqldump for me (or I will do the generation of sql dump manually?) and where can I find it?' Please correct me if Im wrong Thank you.

Comment: Is there any code or process that from sql statement to be executed in my java program. I will generate the sqldump of this archive table without going inside MySQL Workbench. I mean I have my automatic generation of my data into sqldump inside my program? Thank you

Comment: You are probably confusing my answer with peterm's answer. Basically, yes it will take data from table and move into a compressed archive. I don't think it will generate a sqldump by default, but you can give instructions. If you don't intend to do manual dumping, then I think it's better for you to go with peterm's solution.

Comment: Do you have a scheduler or a timer in your program ? Yes, you can create a sql dumper programmatically, have a look here : http://www.bosit.be/blog/2008/03/29/dumping-a-mysql-database-from-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqldump command to archive the whole database or some specific tables.

```
Database Dump:

mysqldump -u "username" -p"password" "databasename" | gzip > /var/www/dump.sql.gz [location and dump file name]

Specific Tables Dump:

mysqldump -u "username" -p"password" "databasename" --tables table1 table2 table3 | gzip > /var/www/dump.sql.gz [location and dump file name]
```