# MySql Workbench: generate insert statements for tables

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

When forward engineering my database, I check the option "Generate INSERT Statements for Tables". However, INSERT statements do not appear in the script file after that.

There's another question with the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255685/export-tables-with-mysql-workbench-with-insert-statements), and I followed the steps detailed in the answer, the answer didn't say where to find the INSERT statements after that, so I tried just forward engineering once again after I exported the data. However, there are still no INSERT statements in the generated script. Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
INSERT INTO customers(Name, Phone, ZipCode, Address) Values ('Angeline', '330-202-5554', '44433', '4344 North Lane Drive'); 
INSERT INTO customers(Name, Phone, ZipCode, Address) Values ('Donald', '330-233-4564', '44304', '234 West 11th Detroit'); 

INSERT INTO customers(Name, Phone, ZipCode, Address) Values ('Jefferey', '550-664-4564', '43563', '35 1/2 North Lane Drive'); 
INSERT INTO customers(Name, Phone, ZipCode, Address) Values ('Steve', '457-202-3563', '44544', '4344 South Park View');

INSERT INTO customers(Name, Phone, ZipCode, Address) Values ('Mike', '354-562-4543', '44343', '4344 North Valley Road');
```

After you forward engineer your script, you will just see all the tables names in that script. If you want to insert data into your tables, you have to manually do that yourself. Which software are you using? MySQL workbench 6.3? For example, look at my insert statements. If you don't want to do that, you can also load pre-generated data into your tables using https://mockaroo.com/. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: @Bob  Did I help you in any way?