# MySQL query recovery

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I created a database for my class and inserted all of my data into the tables but I did not save the queries I used to create them. Is there any way that I can get back the queries I originally used to input all of the data so that I can save them to a separate query tab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export tables with MySQL Workbench with INSERT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255685/export-tables-with-mysql-workbench-with-insert-statements)

Comment: Did you insert it from a linux command line ?

Answer (score 2):

For the tables issue the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>;` command.
For the data you can use a tool like phpMyAdmin or HeidiSQL (Windows) to create an export of the table contents.

Comment: Note: If you use `\G` instead of `;` in the command-line `mysql` tool you'll get much more readable output.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do a `mysqldump --no-data dbname`